# UWP XAML TextBox customization

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Please, I would like to customize a UWP XAML TextBox until it looks like the one on the screenshot below:

[image]

Please, any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with `Border`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **borderthickness** and **textalingment** to achieve what you have shown.

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Right" Text="Textbox with text on right"></TextBox>
```